# Overwriting the GOT entry for __stack_chk_fail in assembly via sprintf format string vulnerability and/or buffer overflow

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64, buffer-overflow

I've got an NX enabled, canary enabled x64 ELF and can only view the assembly, **not** the source code but I do know its written in c. When run, it only accepts command line args and returns nothing. Inside of the main function there's only one function call of note, to `evil`;

```
   0x000000000040060e <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x000000000040060f <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000000000400612 <+4>:     sub    rsp,0x10
   0x0000000000400616 <+8>:     mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
   0x0000000000400619 <+11>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rsi
   0x000000000040061d <+15>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
   0x0000000000400621 <+19>:    add    rax,0x8
   0x0000000000400625 <+23>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax]
   0x0000000000400628 <+26>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x000000000040062b <+29>:    call   0x4005a7 <evil>
   0x0000000000400630 <+34>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000000000400635 <+39>:    leave  
   0x0000000000400636 <+40>:    ret
```

and inside `evil`, it pulls the command line args and checks... something... against 0xdeadbeef and if they match, passes a "you win!" message, then verifies the canary and if either of those fail, it runs `call __stack_chk_fail@plt`, which indirects through a GOT entry which is in writeable memory somewhere.

```
   0x00000000004005a7 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x00000000004005a8 <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x00000000004005ab <+4>:     sub    rsp,0x70
   0x00000000004005af <+8>:     mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x68],rdi
   0x00000000004005b3 <+12>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
   0x00000000004005bc <+21>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
   0x00000000004005c0 <+25>:    xor    eax,eax
   0x00000000004005c2 <+27>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x54],0x0
   0x00000000004005c9 <+34>:    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x68]
   0x00000000004005cd <+38>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x50]
   0x00000000004005d1 <+42>:    mov    rsi,rdx
   0x00000000004005d4 <+45>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x00000000004005d7 <+48>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00000000004005dc <+53>:    call   0x4004b0 <sprintf@plt>
   0x00000000004005e1 <+58>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x54]
   0x00000000004005e4 <+61>:    cmp    eax,0xdeadbeef
   0x00000000004005e9 <+66>:    jne    0x4005f7 <evil+80>
   0x00000000004005eb <+68>:    lea    rdi,[rip+0xd6]        # 0x4006c8
   0x00000000004005f2 <+75>:    call   0x400490 <puts@plt>
   0x00000000004005f7 <+80>:    nop
   0x00000000004005f8 <+81>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
   0x00000000004005fc <+85>:    xor    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
   0x0000000000400605 <+94>:    je     0x40060c <evil+101>
   0x0000000000400607 <+96>:    call   0x4004a0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
   0x000000000040060c <+101>:   leave  
   0x000000000040060d <+102>:   ret
```

In ghidra and with cyclic strings I'm able to verify that the buffer is 72 characters. I've found a bunch of old info from [liveoverflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AahpiYxKR2c) that's about 5 years old now with the exact same problem (protostar format0), except his buffer is 64. For some reason, this buffer mismatch is causing me all sorts of problems I believe.

I've tried hundreds of inputs to achieve the winning statement;

1. I've tried overwriting the buffer of 72 with 72 A's followed by variations of 0xdeadbeef such as little endian, strings, hex, etc
2. I've played around with the buffer and offset, so for example putting 0xdeadbeef and then the buffer after, or putting 72 A's with a nop sled of 8 or so after it then 0xdeadbeef
3. I've tried following liveoverflow's method of overwriting `__stack_chk_fail`'s GOT entry completely, via a format-string vulnerability like `%1640d` which you can see [here](https://asciinema.org/a/lCSEqAqzC9svF29ebwGmO8wH1), but either have the wrong numbers or am misunderstanding how it works/if it will work on my binary and machine

None of these have given me the winning statement, and I'd really like to understand the why and how and the assembly reasoning behind it.

**edit**
I've noticed that if I pass `python -c 'print ("%x."*5)'` as an argument, my stack fills up with `ffffe374.f7fa3658.4006b0.f7fcbb60.0`, which repeats if I up the number from 5. When checking these with `x 0x4006b0`, 0x4006b0 is the only value that reuturns anything of use - `0x4006b0 <__libc_csu_fini>: "\363", <incomplete sequence \303>`. I've tried creating a rop chain using this and looking up ret2csu guides but I've had no luck so far.

Comment: If you're able to step through the code with a debugger then that would be my first thing to do.

Comment: I've stepped through it with pwndbg, and for example I'm able to see when I try the 3rd option that I'm overwriting the stack up to the __stack_chk_fail function but then I'm not able to redirect it to where I want to

Comment: The symbol `__stack_chk_fail` is in `.text`, which is mapped read-only.  You can't plausibly overwrite the machine code there.  Whatever you're talking about, that's not a sensible description.  Maybe you mean overwriting the stack cookie, if you were somehow able to get the program to leak the secret cookie for that thread so you can include it in what you inject and thus overwrite stuff past it.

Comment: @PeterCordes I may not be using the right words, but basically I'm able to mess with format strings by posting `%1640d` to run in to the global offset table, where I'm able to insert my own hex basically wherever I want. I'm just having a hard time finding out what to overwrite and where to put it to either bypass the deadbeef/cookie check OR to just print the winning string and bypass them completely. You can see this in the asciinema I posted in the OP

Comment: The `0xdeadbeef` is directly before the buffer so I think you need a trick to overwrite that with a format string exploit, possibly using wraparound.

Comment: Oh damn, overwriting the GOT entry for `__stack_chk_fail` is clever.  Yeah, since `__stack_chk_fail` is in libc, the call to it from code in the executable indirects through the PLT (or directly inlines `call *__stack_chk_fail@GOTPCREL(%rip)` with `gcc -fno-plt`, but that doesn't change anything, that still uses the same GOT entry).  And since the main executable is non-PIE, there's no ASLR for addresses in it, so both the GOT itself and `evil` are at known absolute addresses.

Comment: I don't see how you could exploit this `sprintf(stack_buffer, argv[1], argv[1])` to overwrite stuff that isn't on the stack, such as a GOT entry.  (The 2nd copy of `argv[1]` is from GCC `-O0` debug-mode code-gen copying it to RDX first.  I'm sure the source was just `sprintf(local_buf, argv[1])`).

Comment: Unless there's something more diabolical you can do with a format string to write to arbitrary addresses.  There are some addresses on the stack, so maybe `%*12s` or something to take the 12th arg to sprintf, aka `[rsp+8 + (12-6)*8]`?  Not sure that works, though, for variadic functions that haven't previously referenced those args to establish their type (some args are wider than others, so it's not necessarily `*8`)

Comment: @PeterCordes I just found a [new way](https://asciinema.org/a/vMyIfvntKlDh2aDBKOiFfZb2r) to crash the program while playing around with different strings and lengths by passing `r "%72d\`echo -en '/xef/xbe/xad/xde'\`%222\$hn"` in gdb - but I'm not sure what exactly to make of it. It looks like I'm jumping to a location inside printf that I've never seen before?

Comment: I get the same results as above every time I change either of the number strings (`%72d` or  `%222\$hn`) to any number not divisible by 8

Comment: Don't you just need to get the `DWORD PTR [rbp-0x54]` to become `0xdeadbeef`?  But that's 4 bytes *before* `[rbp-0x50]`, the start of the buffer sprintf is writing, and below `argv[1]` on the stack.  GCC `-fstack-protector-strong` intentionally puts arrays at higher addresses in the stack frame so it's not as easy as writing past their end to modify other local vars without touching the stack cookie.

Comment: That `printf_positional` store to a numbered arg is what you'd expect from using `%222$hn` in a format string: a 16-bit WORD store of an integer count, to some location using the 222nd arg as a pointer.  Apparently an invalid pointer, since it was just some ASCII bytes.

Comment: @PeterCordes Correct, if `DWORD PTR [rbp-0x54]` became `0xdeadbeef` I'd also get the flag. Is that possible to just change rbp-0x54 like that? I didn't think it was going to be possible to pass the canary without the GOT table exploit since the binary only accepts command line arguments I can't leak the canary THEN submit the command line args.

Comment: I don't see any obvious way to get `sprintf` to store to `[rbp-0x54]`.  I had thought for a second it was at a higher address than `[rbp-0x50]`, but that's not how negative numbers work; that would have been trivial.  :P  IDK what the *intended* solution to your challenge is supposed to be.  (I'm mostly interested in asm for performance reasons, not stuff like this.)